# Hello android giving blank output in windows 7,eclipse classic

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using windows 7- eclipse classic(eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32) - When I run basic hello android I am getting bellow error and in output is black screen with one work Android.

```
[2011-07-08 17:31:31 - Hello Android] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'org.hello.HelloAndroid.HelloAndroid activity launch'!
```

Please help me

Comment: restart eclipse and your emulator

Comment: This did not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created new project with build target Android 1.5 instead of build target Android 3.1.While running I deleted existing AVD which i created with target Andriod 3.1 and just created new AVD with target 'Android 1.5 api level- 3' instead of Andriod 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

You have probally set up your emulator or have it configured wrong.

Give this a try.

In the `IDE-->window--> Show Views --> device--> view menu --> reset adb`

If this does not work try deleting the emulator device and reconfiguring it from scratch.

You may also want to try

1.Select & Right Click on Android Project

2.Run Configurations

3.Go to tab Target

4.Enable option Wipe User Data on Emulator launch parameters

5.Run Application

Comment: I am not getting RESET option.I tried ur second solution too.Still getting 'an andriod virtual device that failed to load' while adding new AVD. I am new to Andriod. tell me if i am missing anything. Till now i didn'd not do any emulator configuration where and how to do it.

Comment: Hi, My problem solved , I just created new AVD with target 'Android 1.5 api level- 3' instead of Andriod 3.1.